# python: Retrieving Youtube media description in Google API (gdata)

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to get user's favourites feed using gdata. What I did was:

```
service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
favorites = service.GetUserFavoritesFeed(username='youtube_username').entry
for favorite in favorites:
    print 'Title: %s' % favorite.media.title.text
    print 'Description %s' % favorite.media.description.text
```

in the line of 'favorite.media.description.text', it gives me an error like:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

While I can get the title without any problem, why there is no text attribute of 'description'?
I can use 'favorite.media.description' and get XML object of description but I cannot use this. How can I parse it? Is there any workaround for this issue to get description text? Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with an user `alexander` and it prints most of the `title/description` for that user. Only gets an exception for one `Private Video`.

When I print the `favorite.media` from python code it returns:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:group xmlns:ns0="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<ns0:title type="plain">Private video</ns0:title>
<ns0:category label="Music" scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Music</ns0:category>
</ns0:group>
```

You can see that it doesn't have any description in it. So I'd suggest you to use a check before printing.

```
if favorite.media.description != None:
    print 'Description %s' % favorite.media.description.text
```